# How can I remove the animation from ListPopupWindow dropdown in Android?

Tags: android, animation, dropdown, popupwindow

How to disable the ListPopupWindow's dropdown animation?

I've tried below setting but still not working when the popupwindow show, it still perform as a default dropdown animation.

```java
popupwindow= ListPopupWindow(this).apply {
            setAdapter(
                ArrayAdapter(
                    this@SampleActivity,
                    R.layout.item_simple_text,
                    arrayOf(stringRes(R.string.paste))
                )
            )
            animationStyle = 0 // this does not work
            anchorView = viewBinding.edittext
            setDropDownGravity(Gravity.END)
            isModal = true
            width = DensityHelper.dp2px(80f)
        }
```